# Check if the variable/key exist

Tags: javascript, json

I have a value customer with different condition :

- if customer = yes then score = 10
- if customer = no then score = 5
- if customer is null then score = 0

My json structure is like this for the first and second condition :

```
json:
  fields:
    customer [1]:
      0 {3}:
        self: aaa
        value: yes
        id: 111
```

And my json structure is like this for the last condition :

```
json:
  fields:
    customer:null
```

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
var customer = json.fields.customer[0].value ;  
var score3 = 0;
    if(typeof customer == 'string'){          
        if(customer === "Yes"){
            score3 = +10;
        }
        else if(customer === "No"){
            score3 = +5;
        }
    }
    else{
        score3 = 0;
    }
```

But I have a problem who says: "Cannot read property '0'"

Thanks for you help

Comment: Rather looks like YAML than JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not check null for customer

```
     var customer = 
json.fields.customer != null && json.fields.customer.length > 0 ? json.fields.customer[0].value : null;
```