# Verify if var exist or not

Tags: javascript, json

I have a value customer with different condition :

- if customer = yes then score = 10
- if customer = no then score = 5
- if customer is null then score = 0

My json structure is like this for the first and second condition :

```
json:
  fields:
    customer [1]:
      0 {3}:
        self: aaa
        value: yes
        id: 111
```

And my json structure is like this for the last condition :

```
json:
  fields:
    customer:null
```

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
var customer = json.fields.customer[0].value ;  
    var score3 = 0;
        if(typeof customer == 'string'){          
            if(customer === "Yes"){
                score3 = +10;
            }
            else if(customer === "No"){
                score3 = +5;
            }
        }
        else{
            score3 = 0;
        }
```

But I have a problem who says: "Cannot read property '0'"

I need to use :

- json.fields.custom[0].value (1 and 2 condition)
- json.fields.custom (last condition)

Thanks for you help

Comment: what is different with this your old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807735/check-if-the-variable-key-exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your code. It worked.

Updated
I create a function with object input and output the score, you can reuse it.

```
function score(json){
var customer = json.fields.customer != null && json.fields.customer.length > 0 ? json.fields.customer[0].value : null;

    var score3 = 0;
        if(typeof customer == 'string'){          
            if(customer === "Yes"){
                score3 = +10;
            }
            else if(customer === "No"){
                score3 = +5;
            }
        }
        else{
            score3 = 0;
        }
        return score3;
}
```

```js
//console.log(json);
function score(json){
var customer = json.fields.customer != null && json.fields.customer.length > 0 ? json.fields.customer[0].value : null;
//console.log(customer)
    var score3 = 0;
        if(typeof customer == 'string'){          
            if(customer === "Yes"){
                score3 = +10;
            }
            else if(customer === "No"){
                score3 = +5;
            }
        }
        else{
            score3 = 0;
        }
        return score3;
}

var json = {
  fields:{
     customers:null
  }
};
        
console.log(score(json));

json = {
  fields:{
     customer:[{
      id: 1,
      value: 'Yes'
     }]
  }
};
//console.log(json)
console.log(score(json));

json = {
  fields:{
     customer:[{
      id: 1,
      value: 'No'
     }]
  }
};
console.log(score(json));
```